# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>
> (`whnkepbk_Hland`.`interests`, CONSTRAINT `interests_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`scale_id`) REFERENCES `scales_reference` (`scale_id`))

I know that the problem is because I have to set value to scale_id to add this data line.

And I do it :

```
    $requete = "INSERT INTO interests (onetsoc_code,element_id,scale_id,data_value) VALUES (:onetsoc_code,:element_id,:scale_id,:data_value)"; 
...           
$InsertMetier->bindParam(':scale_id', $scale);
            var_dump($scale);
            var_dump($InsertMetier);
            $InsertMetier->execute();
```

Here the content of the var_dump :

```
</pre>Ol<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Ol'</font> 

'INSERT INTO interests (onetsoc_code,element_id,scale_id,data_value) VALUES (:onetsoc_code,:element_id,:scale_id,:data_value)'
```

My scale variable do have a value according to the var_dump and my query sounds legitimate.

Here a screenshot of my database (interest) :

[image]

`scales_reference`:

[image]

Structure of interest :

[image]

Structure of `scale_reference` :

[image]

If someone has any idea what I have done wrong.

Comment: Please post a structure of those 2 tables.

Comment: I did the screenshoot you asked :)

Comment: You have showed the contents of the table, not its structure :)

Comment: I just changed it :)

Comment: There must be a constraint - probably on `scale_id` column - that prevents you from inserting a row to the db.

Comment: Yes I know but It should work because I'm trying to respect it, I don't want to delete the constraint .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the difference between Ol and OI you can't even see it on stackoverflow , how about "oi" and "ol", yes there is a big difference and I was not putting "OI" but I was putting OL so that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL error `Integrity constraint violation: 1452` from [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> For storage engines supporting foreign keys, MySQL rejects any INSERT
>   or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a
>   child table if there is no a matching candidate key value in the
>   parent table.

That means you are either:

1. Inserting into your `interest` table with `scale_id` value, which doesn't exist in the parent table (`scale_reference`).
2. Having error in your query and inserting empty `scale_id` - from the code snippet it is not clear how you are replacing all placeholders (`:xx`) with actual values from PHP variables and we don't see the actual query as it is sent to the MySQL server.

You can try to run the desired query directly on MySQL without PHP. If it works, then you have issue in your PHP code.